# Appium Inspector not seeing ids, classes, etc

Tags: automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

On both `iOS` and `Android`, I am unable to locate elements by id or class as `Appium` does not see this info, which does exist when testing on desktop (I am testing an app that is really just a wrapper for a website, but this problem still occurs if I open the site in a mobile browser).
 Some elements do have a name, value, and label, but this is often just the text value of the element.
 The behavior is the same for both native and web view contexts. I can't seem to find anyone online having a similar problem.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Could be something with your Appium setup? Do you have some more things you can show us?

Comment: @KleerCoder - 1. I hope you are using something like  `switch.context(""WEBVIEW")` everytime you want to access access web elements on mobile using appium. 2. Try and check if the elements are visible before you want to perform any action to get to debug the problem.

Comment: @nullpointer they are definitely visible as I am just referring to manually looking in the inspector to figure out a decent locator (which at this point is unfortunately a messy xpath). So I'm also manually switching contexts.

Comment: @Andrej that's what I'm wondering. Do you have anything more specific as to what would be good to add?

Comment: @KleerCoder by visibility i meant check using code

Comment: @nullpointer oh, okay. In that case the elements are visible via code.

Comment: Using automation ID's could help. Views and lists will cause the issue you brought up.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with the Appium inspector, the only things that showed up are the index, text, class, package and sometimes the content-desc.

the problem was that the Appium inspector was open in a web browser, and the CSS properties of the table(index, text, class... resource-id) of the overflow was set to overflow: hidden;

this is the class:

```
.ant-card {
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    transition: all .3s;
```

you have to go to the Appium file folder and fix it:
Appium/resources/node-modules/antd/dist/antd.css

in that CSS file find: .ant-card and change the properties of overflow.

Answer (score 0):

iOS will not have id's , use xpath and names for iOS 
For android device should be above 4.3 for id to be visible in appium inspector , you can use uiautomatorviewer instead of inspector for android

Comment: If you are using webview make sure you switch context to webview before performing the operations , use chrome adb plugin to inspect the elements in your device

Comment: Why won't ios have id's?

Comment: It's os specific , iOS use xpaths created by appium inspector

Comment: what if we need to have a unique identifier for iOS?

Answer (score 0):

Also if you haven't seen you can use the accessibility inspector on iOS simulators to verify elements outside of the Appium inspector if you want to troubleshoot issues.

[Verifying App Accessibility on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/TestingAccessibilityOfiOSApps/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector/TestAccessibilityiniOSSimulatorwithAccessibilityInspector.html)